# curl output not redirecting to file

Tags: http, curl, post, get, libcurl

I am trying to redirect output of curl to a file.
As per man pages of curl, I have to append:

```
--output <file.txt>
```

However, even if I do so, the output isn't getting redirected.
Could someone please guide, what am I doing wrong? I am trying to do the request below:

```
$ curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"json":"data"}' --user email@host.com:password http://host.com/inventory/ --output haha.txt
```

I'm getting the output on terminal/shell but it just won't get to a file.

Comment: You must put `--output haha.txt` *before* the URL!

Answer (score 0):

`--output` (or `-o`) writes the downloaded content into the given file (instead of writing it into stdout). The rest of cURL's output (progress meter, error messages, verbose mode etc.) is still written into stderr, which is shown in the terminal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

You can use cURL's `--stderr` option to redirect that output to a file or your shell's [redirection operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

From the man page:

> ```
>   --stderr
>          Redirect all writes to stderr to the specified file instead. If the file
>          name is a plain '-', it is instead written to stdout.
>
>          If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
>
>          See also -v, --verbose and -s, --silent.
> ```

Using the shell's redirection operator to redirect both output streams as they were printed on the terminal to a file:

```
curl -v https://duckduckgo.com > filename 2>&1
```

Comment: uh why is it filename 2? Is the filename called 2?  what is &1 mean.  Please explain your answer better

Comment: @JPM 1 and 2 are the file descriptors (not filenames!) for the process' standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr) streams (0 would be the standard input stream, stdin). The `x > &y` syntax means "redirect file descriptor x to y".